# What does promise.all do to a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

User.save() is a function with a promise

This will return a object:

```
user = user.save();
return sequelize.Promise.all([user, ...])
    .then((results) => {
        console.log(results[0])
    })
```

but this returns a promise:

```
return sequelize.Promise.all([user, name, fbprofile, phone])
    .then(()=> {
        console.log(user)
    })
```

I would like to use the first one, because I would like to use it like this in a single promise-chain:

```
return sequelize.Promise.all([user, name, fbprofile, phone])
    .then(user.addUserAttributes([name, fbprofile, phone]))
    .then...
```

Comment: So what's the problem? you first sample is fine

Comment: No, because If I try to do the last thing user.addUserAttributes does not exist. And I can't runt it inside the function, because then I create a new promise-chain.

Comment: You seem to be freely interchanging `user` as a database object and a promise that resolves to a database object. You need to keep them separate in your code and in they way you're thinking about this.

Comment: `sequelize.Promise.all([user, ...])` won't return anything; it's a syntax error. Your `then` clause in the second example almost certainly needs to be `.then(([user, name, fbprofile, phone]) => user.addUserAttribute(name, fbprofile, phone))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
return sequelize.Promise.all([user, name, fbprofile, phone])
  .then(user.addUserAttributes([name, fbprofile, phone]))
  .then...
```

will invoke `user.addUserAttributes` when evaluating the statement, which is not what you want, and won't work anyway, since `name` etc. won't be defined. You want to pass a **function** handler to `then`. The function will take as an argument an array of the results of resolving each promise passed to `Promise.all`, which you can deconstruct in place, as in the code below. Then in the function body, invoke the `addUserAttributes` method.

```
return sequelize.Promise.all([user, name, fbprofile, phone]) .
  then([user, name, fbprofile, phone]) =>
    user.addUserAttributes(name, fbprofile, phone)
  );
```

The above assumes that not only `user`, but also `name`, `fbprofile`, and `phone` are promises. If that is not the case, and only `user` is a promise, then there's no reason to even use `Promise.all`. You can just write:

```
return user .
  then(user => user.addUserAttributes(name, fbprofile, phone));
```

and you're done.

I've also assumed that `user#addUserAttributes` takes a list of parameters, rather a single array parameter; if that is not the case, adjust as necessary.

By the way, you say:

> This will return a object:

```
    user = user.save();
    return sequelize.Promise.all([user, ...])
        .then((results) => {
            console.log(results[0])
        })
```

Actually, assuming by "return" you are referring to the value returned by the `return` statement, and not the value printed by `console.log`, it **does** return a promise (resolving to undefined, since the `then` handler returns nothing), **not** an object.

Finally, the title of your question

> What does promise.all do to a variable?

is odd and may reflect your confusion. `Promise.all` does not do anything to any variable. It just evaluates to a promise which will fulfill when all the specified promises fulfill, with its fulfilled value being an array of the individual fulfilled values.

Answer (score -1):

Simply put promise all waits for all variables in an array to be loaded before executing then. Care should be taken when using it though because it is relatively new and not well supported on mobile devices.

Comment: you mean all waits for all deferred  in list to resolve.

Comment: But why isn't the user-variable the same as resluts[0]? (I'm running this serverside so it's ok :) )

Comment: Ones a promise and one is an object meaning when you called return on the promise all the variables hadn't resolved. For instance you could write an image/video preloader with promises for canvas games without using the img.onload etc function.

Comment: But they are running inside promise.all, so shouldn't that mean that they are resolved?

Comment: No you are returning the contents of promise all immediately. Return will not wait for promise to execute.